# JSON to JSON transformation with JOLT and NIFI

Tags: json, transformation, apache-nifi, jolt

I need help with a `JSON` transformation. I'm using `NIFI` to transform a flat `JSON` into a nested `JSON`. I'm using processor `JoltTransformJSON` in version `1.8.0`.

I have this `JSON`:

```
[
   {
      "territoryName":"Bauru",
      "territoryCode":"50",
      "territoryLatitude":1,
      "territoryLongitude":1,
      "branchCode":"80",
      "branchName":"Aracatuba",
      "branchLatitude":1,
      "branchLongitude":1
   },
   {
      "territoryName":"Bauru",
      "territoryCode":"50",
      "territoryLatitude":1,
      "territoryLongitude":1,
      "branchCode":"50",
      "branchName":"Bauru",
      "branchLatitude":1,
      "branchLongitude":1
   },
   {
      "territoryName":"Bauru",
      "territoryCode":"50",
      "territoryLatitude":1,
      "territoryLongitude":1,
      "branchCode":"74",
      "branchName":"Fernandopolis",
      "branchLatitude":1,
      "branchLongitude":1
   }
]
```

And I need an output like this

```
{
   "territoryName":"Bauru",
   "territoryCode":"50",
   "area":[
      {
         "latitude":1,
         "longitude":1
      },
      {
         "latitude":1,
         "longitude":1
      },
      {
         "latitude":1,
         "longitude":1
      }
   ],
   "branches":[
      {
         "branchName":"Aracatuba",
         "branchCode":"80",
         "area":[
            {
               "latitude":1,
               "longitude":1
            },
            {
               "latitude":1,
               "longitude":1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "branchName":"Bauru",
         "branchCode":"50",
         "area":[
            {
               "latitude":1,
               "longitude":1
            },
            {
               "latitude":1,
               "longitude":1
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "branchName":"Fernandopolis",
         "branchCode":"74",
         "area":[
            {
               "latitude":1,
               "longitude":1
            },
            {
               "latitude":1,
               "longitude":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying `JOLT` on line but I can't figure out how to create the spec to do it. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Do you have any example what exactly have you tried and where is the problem?

Comment: hi - this is the spec I'm using. It basically groups all the data on the same list. [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
       "*": {
        "territoryName": {
          "*": { 
            "@(3,[&2])": "&.[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { 
        "$": "&.name",
        "*": { 
          "branchCode|branchName|branchLatitude|branchLongitude": "&4.&[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[#1]"
    }
  }
]

Comment: You can start from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674781/jolt-grouping-together

Comment: thanks, I will check it