# Combine Json Rows using Jolt Nifi Spec

Tags: jolt

Input:

```
[{
    "Store_id": "store_0",
    "Item_id": "item_0",
    "Quantity": "26",
    "Date": "2019-05-01",

}, {
    "Store_id": "store_0",
    "Item_id": "item_0",
    "Quantity": "17",
    "Date": "2019-05-02"
}, {
    "Store_id": "store_0",
    "Item_id": "item_1",
    "Quantity": "47",
    "Date": "2019-05-01",
    "CREATED_DT": "2019-10-09 20:45:47.0",
    "CREATED_BY": "di_user"
}]
```

Output Required:

```
[order: {
    "Store_id": "store_0",
    "Date": "2019-05-01"
    items:[
          {item: item_0 , Quantity:26}]},
{
    "Store_id": "store_0",
    "Date": "2019-05-02"
    items:[
          {item: item_0 , Quantity:17}]}
```

Comment: Please fix you output json, it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If I read yours output correctly, below spec should work:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Store_id": "order[&1].Store_id",
        "Date": "order[&1].Date",
        "Item_id": "order[&1].items[#].item",
        "Quantity": "order[&1].items[#].Quantity"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, Magda. But I want to group all the records based on matching Srore_id and Date. This Spec is giving only one record per grouping. for example, if I have 10 different Items for one store and one Date, I should have a array of all [{Item: item_id1,Quantity:Quant1}, {Item: item_id2,Quantity:Quant2},{Item: item_id3,Quantity:Quant3}, ...... So on]

Comment: Oh, now I see. I think that this answer is similar to yours problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674781/jolt-grouping-together